# substitute for ngx-datatable-group-footer

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Like we have ngx-datatable-group-header, we don't have ngx-datatable-group-footer. However, if we want to display something in the footer in a group level, what can we do? Like I have a requirement to display the number of rows in a group level in the footer of each group but am unable to do that because there is no ngx-datatable-group-footer. The current functionality which I am able to achieve is displaying the total no of rows(not an individual group level). Any ideas anyone?

Here's my code snippet below:

```
 <ngx-datatable #table
                       class='datatable'
                       [sortType]="'single'"
                       [columns]="columns"
                       [columnMode]="'flex'"
                       [headerHeight]="40"
                       [footerHeight]="50"
                       [rowHeight]="'auto'"
                       [groupRowsBy]="'isCurrentDate'"
                       [limit]="10"
                       [rows]='rows'
                       [groupExpansionDefault]="true"
                       [scrollbarH]="true">

            <ngx-datatable-group-header [rowHeight]="60" #myGroupHeader>
                <ng-template let-group="group" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-group-header-template>
                    <div style="padding-left:5px;">
                        <a title="Expand/Collapse Group"
                           (click)="toggleExpandGroup(group)">
                            <b>{{group.value[0].isCurrentDate === true? 'Scheduled for Today':'Scheduled for other days'}}</b>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-group-header>

            <ngx-datatable-footer>
                <ng-template ngx-datatable-footer-template
                             let-rowCount="rowCount">
                    <div style="padding: 5px 10px">
                        <div>
                            {{rowCount}} total 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-footer>

        </ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: Was wondering if you ever got the footer to work? I'm struggling in understanding how 'let-rowCount="rowCount"' works. Can you tell me where the heck rowCount is being set?